# can't download android studio 2023 in macbook air

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to update Android Studio (from 2022 giraffe to 2023 hedgehog) but when I go to their site the old version keeps appearing, why? Thank you very much

I performed the following steps.
android studio > settings > Appearance and Behavior > Updates.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKdVE.jpg)
It tells me that there is a new version but if I click on download it makes me download Android Studio 2022 Giraffe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpDcN.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the exact same thing today. I tried other methods like using the Jetbrain Toolbox App or trying to download it directly from the [Android Studio download archives page](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). In the end, I realized that the problem is that this Hedgehog version is not available in certain countries. In my case, I had the VPN connected. After disconnecting it, I was able to update directly from Android Studio as well as from the previously mentioned methods.

Comment: thank you very much I solved it using the Jetbrain Toolbox

Answer (score 0):

Same! I think that there are big changes from v2022 to v2023, it needs to be reinstalled.
Normally updates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0iN4urTNI4&ab_channel=iRekhaTechSolutions